# Can I bring Swiss cheese into Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, switzerland

Title says it all: I gather the answer is "yes", but wasn't able to find an authoritative source.

For extra credit, distinguish between these three types:

1. "Hard" cheeses (Gruyere etc)
2. "Soft" cheeses (mozzarella etc)
3. Prepacked fondue mix (cheese, wine & spices, just reheat and eat)

Comment: Are any of the cheeses 'raw' (unpasturized)?

Comment: In reverse (Canada -> EU/Switzerland) it would definitely be illegal.

Comment: Pasteurized vs. unpasteurized milk is also sometime a relevant distinction I think (although not in this case I think).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you must **declare** all food, even food that is allowed.

Second, according to [the CFIA web site](http://inspection.gc.ca/food/information-for-consumers/travellers/what-can-i-bring-into-canada-/eng/1389648337546/1389648516990) you may bring:

> cheese: up to 20 kilograms per person

You may not bring:

> milk, milk products (whey, cream, skim milk, butter oil, and so on) dried, frozen, reconstituted, or fresh

Note they do not distinguish among cheese types as you have done - it's all allowed. (I personally suspect raw cheese might be an issue but the web site doesn't say so. Obviously being in sealed, professionally-labelled packages helps.) A friend brought rather a lot of fondue mix home from a Swiss trip and I presume she declared it. She was able to bring it in without issues.

Comment: What about: 'When are documents required? Some items ... may require documents such as permits issued in Canada in advance and/or certificates from the country of origin. These include: ... dairy products ... To request permits contact the Centre of Administration for Permissions. If you do not have the required documents, the items will not be allowed to enter Canada.'

Comment: The same site also says your 20kg should cost less than $20 or you may get slapped with duties - good luck with that in Switzerland!

Comment: I think that's a typo. I think they meant to say if you have more than the 20kg they just mentioned, expect to pay duties. You could always ask them, though...

Comment: @KateGregory No, it is clearly stated on other information sites as well, that you have to pay import duty for cheese if it's worth more than CAD 20. For most types of cheese, the import duty is 245.5%.

Comment: For the record, this answer is correct.  I declared my cheese at immigration, the officer wrote a magic scribble on the landing card and on seeing it Customs waved me through without even opening my bag.

Comment: @jpatokal wait so was it 20kg or 20$ ? Man wish I knew this last time I was coming back from France !

Comment: @blackbird57 Both!